# Greedy hyperlink texts

Tags: support, status-norepro, hyperlinks, markdown

Consider the following answer of mine: [Symbian Series 40/60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098031/symbian-series-40-60/1098265#1098265)

```
[Nokia Series 40](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Technology_Topics/Device_Platforms/Series_40/)
is based on Nokia's proprietary operating system. For third party application
development, you can use Java ME and MIDP, Flash Lite or widgets (i.e.
XHTML+CSS+Javascript).
```

In preview the hyperlink displays correctly, but on the actual answer it takes the whole paragraph to be the hyperlink text.

---

Update: There was another hyperlink issue in my answer:

```
For both, you can find the tools and SDKs from
[http://www.forum.nokia.com](Forum Nokia), alongside other developer resources.
```

which should have been

```
For both, you can find the tools and SDKs from
[Forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com), alongside other developer resources.
```

Fixing this made the issue mentioned above disappear: Now the Series 40 link text displays as I intended.

However, the issue still remains: Preview and final were showing different formatting.

Comment: I've had a similar issue on a post. When posting an answer with multiple links with anchors, two entire paragraphs were gobbled up and treated (incorrectly) as a hyperlink. Everything looked good in preview, but went beserk when posted. After I removed the anchors from the links, all was good again. Here's the post, if it helps for comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1109158/list

Answer (score 4):

Carl, your "bug" is right here:

```
* <a href="http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/>Counterclockwise</a>
                                                     ^
                                           missing closing quote
```

I fixed it in your post.

[Clojure editor/IDE recommendations on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257333/clojure-editor-ide-recommendations-on-os-x/1699579#1699579)

And I upvoted you for your troubles.

Comment: Upvoted so your answer would be "above" in two views.

Comment: Most embarrassing that I was the cause of the bug! Thanks for the fix, the info and the upvote.